# How to use Spring RestTemplate instead of Apache Httpclient?

Tags: java, spring, apache, rest, spring-mvc

I want to use Spring `RestTemplate` instead of Apache `HttpClient` for working with a remote API

> With **HttpClient**

```
// build request JSON
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("username", username);
json.put("serial", serial);
json.put("keyId", keyId);
json.put("otp", otp);

String json_req = json.toString();           

// make HTTP request and get response
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(AuthServer);
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(json_req));

response = client.execute(request);
```

> With **RestTemplate**

```
Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
paramMap.put("username", userName);
paramMap.put("serial", serial);
paramMap.put("keyId", keyId);
paramMap.put("otp", otp);

String mapAsJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(paramMap);

HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(mapAsJson,requestHeaders);

try {
  ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(AuthServer, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

  return response.getHeaders();
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
  return null;
}
```

}

The code with `HttpClient` works but that with `RestTemplate` does not. I don't know how to use `StringEntity` in `RestTemplate`.

Spring version is 3.0.0, and JVM is 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

`RestTemplate` is better suited to working with objects. As an example:

> **AuthenticationRequest.java**

```
class AuthenticationRequest {
  private String username;
  private String serial;
  private String key;
  private String otp;
}
```

> **AuthenticationResponse.java**

```
class AuthenticationResponse {
  private boolean success;
}
```

> **AuthenticationCall.java**

```
class AuthenticationCall {
  public AuthenticationResponse execute(AuthenticationRequest payload) {
    HttpEntity<AuthenticationRequest> request = new HttpEntity<AuthenticationRequest>(payload, new HttpHeaders());

    return restTemplate.exchange("http://www.domain.com/api/endpoint"
                                 , HttpMethod.POST
                                 , request
                                 , AuthenticationResponse.class).getBody();
  }
}
```

These classes can be used as follows:

```
if(new AuthenticationCall().execute(authenticationRequest).isSuccess()) {
  // Authentication succeeded.
}
else {
  // Authentication failed.
}
```

---

All of this requires there to be a JSON library such as Jackson or GSON on the classpath.

Comment: Thank you! i'll try this one.

Comment: This is very useful answer,but I can't solve my problem.
I recive that model, but webapi give me status 401..

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: HTTP 401 is thrown when the API requires authentication. Is your request missing authentication parameters?

Comment: I want this program
1. Check token
2. if return 401, update token
3. create otp
4. Update token to api **here HttpClient is worked. but restTemplate is not.

So, I want same HttpClient request to made by RestTemplate

Comment: This seems to be specific to your application. Can't help further.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for spend your time for me!